# How to find index of specific PFObject within array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uipickerview

I have a `listPicker:UIPickerView!` that is populated with the `clientName:String` attribute of an array of PFObjects. This pickerView is inside of the EditViewController that is used to edit the details of existing PFObjects (displayed in the parent TableViewController). The PFObjects for the listPicker are queried within the EditViewController, separate from the query for the parent TableViewController.

Inside of the EditViewController's viewDidLoad I am trying to call `self.listPicker.selectRow(self.dealIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)` so that the selected row in the pickerView matches the existing value for `clientName` from the parent TableViewController.

**I'm trying to find the index of the existing `clientName` within the listPicker to set the value of `dealIndex`. I think that I'm close with the code below, by creating a parallel dealArray:NSMutableArray and calling `self.dealIndex = dealArray.indexOfObject(dealString)`, but this isn't working for some reason.**

To clarify the `if let` statements, my Task class has a pointer to the Deal class, which has a pointer to the Client class, which includes the attribute "clientName". These clientName values populate the listPicker.

Below are the code snippets as well as the relevant surrounding code. Currently when I run it, I get the error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableIndexSet addIndexesInRange:]: Range {9223372036854775807, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1'` I believe this is due to `self.listPicker.selectRow(self.dealIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)` not functioning properly.

```
for object in dealObjects {
        if let client = object["client"] as? PFObject {
            if let clientName:NSString = client["clientName"] as? NSString {

                dealArray.addObject(clientName)

            }
        }
    }
```

--

```
if (self.object != nil) {

        if let deal = self.object["deal"] as? PFObject {
            if let client = deal["client"] as? PFObject {
                if let clientName = client["clientName"] as? String {

                    self.deal_Btn.setTitle(clientName, forState: .Normal)
                    self.dealString = clientName as NSString
                }
            }
        }

        self.dealIndex = dealArray.indexOfObject(dealString)
        self.listPicker.selectRow(self.dealIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

}
```

**Code in context:**

```
import UIKit

class EditViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var dealObjects:NSMutableArray!
var newDeal:PFObject!

var dealIndex:Int!
var dealString:NSString!
var dealArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet weak var deal_Btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var listPicker: UIPickerView!

//Client listPicker Query
func fetchAllDeals() {
    var dealQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Deal")
    dealQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    dealQuery.includeKey("client")
    dealQuery.orderByAscending("clientName")

    self.dealObjects = NSMutableArray()

    dealQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (deals, error) -> Void in
        if (deals == nil) {
            println(deals)
        } else if (error == nil) {

            var temp:NSArray = deals! as NSArray
            self.dealObjects = temp.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
            println(deals)

            self.listPicker.reloadAllComponents()

            println("Fetched clients from server")

        } else {
            println(error?.userInfo)
        }
    }

    for object in dealObjects {
        if let client = object["client"] as? PFObject {
            if let clientName:NSString = client["clientName"] as? NSString {

                dealArray.addObject(clientName)

            }
        }
    }
}

//MARK: - Task object data
var object:PFObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchAllDeals()

    listPicker.delegate = self
    listPicker.dataSource = self


    //Dismiss keyboard for touches outside of text field
    var gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideKeyboard")
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    if (self.object != nil) {

        if let deal = self.object["deal"] as? PFObject {
            if let client = deal["client"] as? PFObject {
                if let clientName = client["clientName"] as? String {
                    self.deal_Btn.setTitle(clientName, forState: .Normal)
                    self.dealString = clientName as NSString
                }
            }
        }

        self.dealIndex = dealArray.indexOfObject(dealString)
        self.listPicker.selectRow(dealIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

    } else {
        self.object = PFObject(className: "Task")
    }
}

//MARK: - Delegates and data sources
//MARK: Data sources
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return dealObjects.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    let object:PFObject = dealObjects[row] as! PFObject
    var rowClientName = String()
    if let client = object["client"] as? PFObject {
        if let clientName = client["clientName"] as? String {
            rowClientName = clientName
        }
    }

    return rowClientName
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let object:PFObject = dealObjects[row] as! PFObject
    self.newDeal = object

    if let client = object["client"] as? PFObject {
        if let clientName:String = client["clientName"] as? String {
            deal_Btn?.setTitle(clientName, forState: .Normal)

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can we see the current code you have?

Comment: @sarvesh I've added the relevant code. Thanks for taking a look.